# What's the interpretation of the intercept of a linear mixed effect model with only one group

Tags: linear-model, intercept

I'm trying to understand the meaning of the intercept term in a linear mixed model. The caveat here is that the dataset the LME will be built upon will only consist of subjects from a single class (group). All subjects will have technical replicates, some more than others. Thus, the formula is as follows:

$y = B0 + (1|\text{subject})$

The subject is the random effect (to account for intra subject variance), y is the response variable and B0 is the intercept. My understanding when doing some prior searching is that this could be intepreted as a "mean model", with the "mean" being the B0. However that is in the context of a linear model, not a linear mixed effect model.

Thus I was wondering if someone could help shed some light on to what the B0 means in this case (especially given the fact that the dataset consists of subjects from one class (group) only), and if it is a valid method in getting a "group representative value". For example I run the above LME on two separate groups (group $A$ and group $B$) such that I now have

$B_{0_A} $ and $B_{0_B} $

Would it be a valid to then run a statistical test using the above group representative values given that they were not quantified from the classical method of averaging? To clarify, I will also have the standard error of B0_A and B0_B from the algorithm used (fitlme in MATLAB)

Comment: Whenever we include a random effect in our model, we assume said random effect has mean 0. In your case, $B_0$ represents the baseline intercept for all samples, regardless of subject. The inclusion of (1|subject) in the model ensures that the baseline intercept accounts for the dependency of samples coming from the same subject.

Comment: @JLinsta So does that mean that the intercept estimated with resepct to the random effect will be different from what is the arithmetic mean? If so, how does the dependency of the samples from the same subject affect the baseline intercept? Does it modify 'weights' for particular subjects dependent on intra subject variance, or inter subject variance?

Comment: I believe the estimated intercept with respect to the random effect could differ from the arithmetic mean if the number of responses per subject is not consistent.

The inclusion of the random intercept, will also affect the standard error of your estimated intercept. Some of the variance will be attributed to the random effect instead of ordinary sampling error. This changes the significance test for the intercept term.

Comment: @JLinsta Which one would you think would be a more preferrable group representative value? If there are samples with uneven number of responses, it could also skew the arithmetic mean since the value for those responses would come from a better defined distribution. Even though the weights across all responses for the arithemtic mean are equal, it would then seem to hide the fact that there were uneven sample variances, whilst the LME method would reflect that better. What are your thoughts on it?

Comment: As you said, the ordinary arithmetic mean will be biased towards the subjects with more responses. **This is a problem if you believe the errors among replicates from the same subject are correlated**. In other words, if you think each subject's replicates are correlated, then you must account for this correlation with the mixed effect (1|subject).